# 'com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2' when doing "Building REST services with Spring" tutorial

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm pretty new with Spring framework. On [the official tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/), when i replace

```
@GetMapping("/employees")
List<Employee> all() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

by the following in my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/employees")
Resources<Resource<Employee>> all() {

    List<Resource<Employee>> employees = repository.findAll().stream()
            .map(employee -> new Resource<>(employee,
                    linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(employee.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                    linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withRel("employees")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new Resources<>(employees,
            linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
}
```

I have this error when i try to connect to http://localhost:8080/employees/ :

[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQfFN.png) (click)

Can you help me please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some strange accented characters that you are trying to parse. Try to add

```
spring.datasource.url=[your_db_connection_string]?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

to your database connection string.

Try to use this:

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

for embedded h2 database.

Comment: thanks for answer. I use a H2 in-memory database. Where can i fin the db connection string?

Comment: application.properties

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` in my `@GetMapping` annotation like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/employees", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```